# Post accessibility notification in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uiaccessibility, uiaccessibility-notification

I need to move the accessibility focus to a certain element on the screen. In UIKit, I can simply call `UIAccessibility.post(.screenChanged, element)`.

When I do that with a SwiftUI View, the app crashes with the following message in console:

```
This class '__SwiftValue' is not a known serializable element and returning it as an accessibility element may lead to crashes
```

Any idea how I can move focus to certain elements on the screen in SwiftUI?

Comment: `element` must be UIView (reference-type), it is not applicable to SwiftUI view (value-type)

Comment: So how can one achieve the same behavior in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be: Post a notification when the UIView appears:

```
    .onAppear(perform: {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: "New Screen")
        }
    })
```

As argument it would make sense to put in the text of the accessibility label of the desired view. The impaired user would just not know where the screenReader is focusing if the user could recognize the white surrounding of the screenReader focus.

To make things smooth the delay of `0.1` should be adapted while testing with different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try [accessibilityFocused(_:equals:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accessibilityfocused(_:equals:))

```
enum FocusedView: Hashable {
     case A
}

SomeView {
    @AccessibilityFocusState var focus: FocusedView?

    var body: some View {
        SomeButton()
           .accessibilityFocused($focus, equals: .A)
    }
}
```

If you want set focus to SomeButton,

```
focus = .A
```